# Не работает Hello World в Visual Studio

Tags: c#

пробовал сам сделать хелло ворлд на c#, ругается
скачал с гитхаба, тоже не работает, может кто-то сталкивался с таким[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что ты устанавливал помимо студии?

Comment: Где-то неправильно указаны пути, возможно стоит заменить в файле проекта пути, как это указано тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694/the-imported-project-c-microsoft-csharp-targets-was-not-found Открыть csproj в редакторе любом и заменить `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` на `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`.

Comment: Вы его в дебри посылаете, с настройками проекта. Тут больше проблемы с msbuild под mac. К примеры этот - https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/14875 одно из решений - откатиться на предыдущую версию mono. Preferences > .net runtime. Ну или посмотрите, может уже вышли  обновления, для вашей ide / .net core

Comment: @Dev, это ответ на EnSO, который помогал людям решить эту проблему т.к. в новой версии mono как раз таки изменились пути. Вроде легче поменять строчку в файле, чем делать откаты и сидеть на старых версиях.